# Creating a report with TeX using data from DICOM file

Tags: automation, import

The DICOM standard used in medical imaging contains detailed information about the performed medical diagnostic procedure. There are open-source DICOM toolkits that can handle data from DICOM files. TeX can be used in an automated data-collection system. For example, the DICOM file contains the name of the patient, the date of the study, the equipment used, measurements made, etc.. The final report should contain this information and typeset it with TeX or LaTeX.

Is it possible to automatically create a medical report with LaTeX or TeX using extracted DICOM data?

Comment: I don't know. I think this would be possible using the computer algebra system SAGE along with the `sagetex` [package](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex). From [here](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/38090/dicom-files-with-sage/) I see SAGE can handle Dicom files with pydicom. From the Cocalc site, which runs SAGE and LaTeX and much more we find [pydicom](https://cocalc.com/doc/software-python.html) is supported.  A pydicom user guide is [here](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/pydicom_user_guide.html). This would be a natural possibility to explore if nobody has an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will have to take a look at SAGE, which I wasn't aware of.  I had also considered pydicom as a possibility.

Comment: The online site [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) is the easiest way to experiment with SAGE. The documentation for SAGE is [here](https://www.sagemath.org/).